# Mi Servidor se reinicia

Tags: servidor, hardware, ram

Compré hace unos días un servidor IBM X3200 M3 y ahora que le instale Ubuntu Server

Cuenta con un Dual core 2.53ghz
1 GB RAM ECC

Se reinicia solo, cada 6 minutos aproximadamente.

Y no es cosa de Software porque si inicio la BIOS también pasa lo mismo.

Probé instalar el sistema operativo en el disco desde otro PC y al iniciar el servidor va normal y a los 6 minutos se reinicia

Recibo ideas

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic].

Comment: Me encanta tu espíritu de ayudar

Comment: Gracias. Siempre intento ayudar cuando es posible. Pero en el caso de tu pregunta, la misma está fuera de tema. Podrías realizar tu pregunta en [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Allí sería válido preguntar sobre *hardware* y configuraciones. Lamentablemente no existe un sitio como *Super User* en castellano, por lo cual debes formular tu pregunta en inglés. Aquí en [es.so] sólo se aceptan preguntas de programación, código y que sean específicas al desarrollo de software y que no se basen en opiniones. Espero que eso te sirva de ayuda. Saludos